# Firebase query returns empty object from node but not API

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database whose structure looks a bit like

```
  - game
      - 1000
          - clues: ...
          - grid: ...
          - gid: 1000
          - createTime: ...
          - pid: 2780
       - 1001
          - clues: ... 
          - ...
```

I want to retrieve all games whose pid is 2780. I have set an `.indexOn` rule on `game` for `pid`. In node, I'm currently doing:

```
db.ref('game').orderByChild('pid').equalTo(this.pid).once('value').then(
        gameSnap => {
            console.log(gameSnap.hasChildren());  // false
            console.log(gameSnap.val()); // null
                gameSnap.forEach(
                    childSnap => {
                        console.log(childSnap); // no printout
                        this.setState(prevState => {
                            games: [...prevState.games, [childSnap.key, gameSnap.child("createTime").val()]]
                        });
                    });
        }
    );
```

But `gameSnap` is always empty. In contrast, when I perform the same query of the database through the REST API using the python `Pyrebase` client, I get different results:

```
In [257]: len(db.child('game').order_by_child('pid').equal_to(2780).get().each())
Out[257]: 25
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `this.pid` is the value you expect?  Just asking because you hard coded the value in your python sample.

Comment: Did you check that this.pid is correct?

Comment: I deleted a `console.log(this.pid)` before posting this, which was correct IIRC, but I'll try hardcoding it.

Comment: try `console.log(childSnap.id + " is id and val is " + childSnap.val());`

Comment: sljkhasdkljhskljhasdf `this.pid` is `"2780"`, it isn't `2780`, so it prints right but doesn't get found in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that `this.pid` is `"2780"`, it isn't `2780`. So adding a `parseInt` solved my problems.